# How can I connect to my server without outside ip adress from another network?

Tags: sql-server, networking, hosting, ip-address, windows-server-2008

I want to connect to my server from another network, my server hasn't got an outside ip adress. I want to reach the sql server from where I host my website. I host my website somewhere else (not in my network).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SQL Server will have to be visible to the server from which you host your website.

I'm assuming you want to access the data in SQL Server to generate some content for your website.

There are 2 simple ways to do this:

1. Static IP - Ask your ISP for a static IP address for your local
   network, you can use this in the connection string. This is preferable & more stable, since it will always be in sync.
2. Dynamic DNS - If your ISP won't give you a static address or you don't want to pay for it. You sign up with a DDNS service provider, they give you a domain name, like ferrysqlserver.ddns.org, and your network is visible to the internet via that name. Some routers support DDNS, otherwise you may have to run a service application that keeps your external ip address in sync with your DDNS provider.

Once you have either of those working, your network is now available to the internet, but nothing is likely accessible.
What you have done so far is to create a path from an internet name to your local router.

To make SQL Server accessible, you need to find out which ports your SQL Server uses (default is 1433). It's possible you may need to open other ports as well if you connect to SQL in a different way.

On your router, find the port forwarding options, and enable port forwarding to the **local network ip address** of your SQL Server, for port 1433.

This step maps connections from the internet to port 1433 of your router, and forwards those connections to port 1433 of your SQL Server.

Good luck.